# Adding two times stored as NSdates

Tags: ios, nsdate

this problem is really driving me crazy!  It seems like it should be so simple..

I have two NSDates... They represent total duration for an activity.  I have many activities and I need to loop through these activities and add all of the time spent together to get a total amount of time spent on all activities.  The time spent on each activity is stored as a NSDate.

How can I add these durations together to get a total amount of hours?!

Activity1 - duration is 6:20
Activity2 - duration is 2:20

How can I make a calculation using the two NSDates to return me a NSDate or a number with the correct total of hours spent which would be 8:40?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be using `NSDate` for that, `NSDate` represents a moment in time, not a duration.

Use `NSTimeInterval` for that, and simply add them togheter

For example, for 380 seconds:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 380;
```

Or, for 6:20:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 6*60 + 20;
```

Or even easier, use integers

Comment: He does not have NSDates, he just has durations which by fault he has declared them as nsdates. Why should he use NSTimeInterval and how?

Comment: It comes from the very deffinition of it, nstimeinterval represents a time interval, and nsdate represents a date

Answer (score -1):

You want to calculate durations. A duration is independent from time zones so you do not need `NSDate`.
The easiest way to do this is to calculate the sum of all durations in seconds and then convert it to hours and minutes.

Comment: `NSDate` objects *are* completely independent from time zones.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe yes Objects _are_ and duration _is_.

Comment: I was questioning your reason why the OP shouldn't use `NSDate`. I tried to point out that the `NSDate` class and its objects are not aware of time zones.

Comment: Because he is not aware of time, he does not know when activity 1 starts, he just knows durations and want to calculate durations.

Comment: Clarification: In your answer you are saying that NSDate is not suited for the job because the OP's problem is not related to time zones. That's a misleading way to put it because NSDate objects are completely independent from time zones.

Comment: You are free to edit accordingly, but you get the point of my answer.